# Features in Images Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

As it is known that there are several features in the dataset for the machine learning model. Do the dataset that has only pictures also contain features?

As they can't be opened in excel file, do they contain features?

My project is on **PLANT DISEASE DETECTION USING DEEP LEARNING** and my professor is asking about the features in the dataset.

I don't know what to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the right place to ask such general question in ML (that would be Cross-Validated I guess). That being said:

> So do they contain features?

A feature depends on you and what information you would want to retrieve from it. This means to a certain extent, everything "contains" a feature.

picture datas can always be mapped/transformed into observation-variable dataset where your observation is your picture, and the number of variables/features are arbitrary being an 1D array feature describing the variation of each area in each of your images. The greater your vector is,the more efficient your model will be.

Of course, this is just to answer your question about the how-to theorically as you asked. In practice, you'll need some tool to do that, but I am sure you'll find.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you @renaud. I was just confused and hence asked a silly question. Thank you for clarifying my doubt

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset contains only pictures, features are just **hidden in those pictures**. You need to extract them automatically using a CNNs - Convolutional Neural Networks for example.

Suppose this is your original image

[image]

If you visualize the layers of your CNN (the feature maps from the output of the very first layer for example)

[image]

Bright areas are the “activated” regions, meaning the filter detected the pattern it was looking for. This filter seems to encode an eye and nose detector.

Keep reading about CNNs here https://towardsdatascience.com/applied-deep-learning-part-4-convolutional-neural-networks-584bc134c1e2.

From that medium story, I took these photos.